# run a java program with lingpipe classes on a website?

Tags: java, web-applications, nlp

I am working on a text classification project for a class and I am having some difficulties setting it up correctly. My classification code is in Java and uses methods from the Lingpipe toolkit, but I have to run the program from a website. I've been attempting to put together a servlet for this purpose, and so far have downloaded and set up a container (Tomcat), but I'm finding the process of setting up all the necessary files in the right directories to be complicated. Does anyone out there have any advice as to how to run such a Java program from a website, either using a servlet or not?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way handle dependencies and create WAR is to use Maven. You need to put lingpipe library into your local repository /home/{$username}/.m2 . Create maven project with web project archetype and put lingpipe as dependency. Easiest java web framework for me is play framework.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put dependency jars (including the LingPipe jar) in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application.

Classes you develop yourself, including your servlet class(es) can either be packaged into a jar and deployed in the same WEB-INF/lib directory or placed directly in the WEB-INF/classes directory (in Java's standard package-as-directory format - e.g. com.foo.MyServlet is deployed as WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/MyServlet.class).

A reasonable summary is available at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-web-apps/web-app-directory-layout.html.

One caveat - you probably want to look into the LingPipe license. At one point LingPipe considered moving to the AGPL, but apparently they decided not to make that move; their license is a bit unusual, and the terms thereof may affect your web application deployment.